# Error in extracting tweets using R (sentiment analysis)

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, sentiment-analysis, tweets

After connecting to API's of twitter and connecting to libraries in R,
comes next is extraction and analyzing of tweets which I am unable to do due to error.
The code that I used is

```
# The function for extracting and analyzing tweets
search <- function(searchterm) {
  # Extract tweets and create storage file
  list <- searchTwitter(searchterm, cainfo='cacert.pem', n=1500)   
  df <- twListToDF(list)
  df <- df[, order(names(df))]
  df$created <- strftime(df$created, '%Y-%m-%d')
  if (file.exists(paste(searchterm, '_stack.csv'))==FALSE) {
     write.csv(df, file=paste(searchterm, '_stack.csv'), row.names=F)
  }
}
```

I get the following ERRORS:

```
df <- twListToDF(list)
```

> Error in twListToDF(list) :    Elements of twList are not of an
>   appropriate class

```
df <- df[, order(names(df))]
```

> Error in order(names(df)) : argument 1 is not a vector

```
df$created <- strftime(df$created, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

> Error in df$created : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

I am using R 3.4.2 and RStudio (latest version)

Comment: How did you run your function?

Comment: in console,first i connected the libraries then connected to API and then used the function for extraction of tweets. i am using this as reference https://analyzecore.com/2014/04/28/twitter-sentiment-analysis/